# php memcached which server being used in a pool

Tags: php, memcached

I'm using php memcached (pool of memcached nodes, not just 1 server).

Most of the stuffs I can set in memcached, but there's one particular key that fails to set. So I'm trying to find out which node is the problematic one. Is there any way to know which node is a particular key being set?

Thank you.

Comment: If only 1 particular key is failing, then maybe the key is the fault?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$failure_callback` in `Memcache::addServer`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php or look at `Memcache::getExtendedStats` https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.getextendedstats.php